# Counting sum of numbers in a for loop

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Integer> rNums=new ArrayList<>();
    int rndmNum=0;
    Random rndm=new Random();
    int sum=0;
    
    do {
        rndmNum = 1+rndm.nextInt(9);
        rNums.add(rndmNum);
        sum += rndmNum;
    } while (sum <= 100);
    }
    
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println(rNums);
        
    }

}
```

Hi, I am trying to make it so that this loop counts the sum of all random numbers generated, and when the sum reaches 100 it stops and prints the sum, I could use some help!

Comment: `sum += i;` is adding the loop index.  I think you wanted `sum += rndmNum;`

Comment: Shouldn't `sum+=i;` be `sum+=rndmNum;`?

Comment: Note that your debugger is precisely the tool to identify mistakes like this as you step through your program's execution and examine how your values are changing.

Comment: Do you want the loop to stop before or after you reach 100?

Comment: Does anyone you know how exactly i could count the amount of times each number appears in the arraylist, Ive started with a for loop but not sure what to do next

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

`sum += i;`

You should do:

`sum += rndmNum;`

Your original code sums up the iterator, `i` while the loop is still running, while it should be summing up all the values of `rndmNum`.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Edit: You can output the amount of numbers generated and how many of each by using this code:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Integer> rNums=new ArrayList<>();
    int rndmNum=0;
    Random rndm=new Random();
    int sum=0;
    int[] diffNums = new int[10];
    for (int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
        rndmNum=1+rndm.nextInt(9);
        rNums.add(rndmNum);
        diffNums[rndmNum]++;
        sum += rndmNum;
        if (sum>=100) {
            System.out.println(i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println(rNums);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      System.out.println(i + ": " + diffNums[i] + " times ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx how would I go about counting the amount of numbers generated then printing it

Comment: You can use the iterator to just output the amount of numbers generated. You can just add a System.out.print(i + 1); in your if statement when you break.

Comment: Do you know how exactly i could count the amount of times each number appears in the arraylist, Ive started with a for loop but not sure what to do next

Comment: You can create an array with elements 0 to 9, and every iteration of the for loop, increment the index of the array that matches the random number generated. Let me know if you need me to code this.

Comment: Can i see like a rough layout plz

Comment: I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to do...while loop in such a problem.

```java
      public static void main(String... ar) {
        ArrayList<Integer> rNums = new ArrayList<>();
        int rndmNum = 0;
        Random rndm = new Random();
        int sum = 0;
        do {
            rndmNum = rndm.nextInt(9);
            rNums.add(rndmNum);
            sum += rndmNum;
        } while (sum <= 100);

        System.out.println(sum);
        rNums.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: But if i do that how could i count the numbers generated, Thats why i used a for loop

Comment: size of your arraylist, is your answer.

Comment: Thx appreciate it